# Gradle and changing variables in configuration phase

Tags: gradle

I have the following simplified build.gradle

```
ext.greeting = "not set"

task configHello{
    project.greeting = "Hello"
    doLast{
        project.greeting = "I said hello"
    }
}

task configGoodbye{
    project.greeting = "Goodbye"
}

task print(dependsOn: configHello){
    def localString = project.greeting
    doLast{
        println project.greeting
        println localString
    }
}
```

Running **gradle print** gives:
:configHello
:print
I said hello
Goodbye

What I would like is that it said **"Hello"**. How should I set **localString** in a nice way?  Or am I going about this the wrong way? The real life scenario the print task is a JavaExec type, but I found this a little easier to understand.

Edit: Or is configuring the print task via DAG the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Well, found the answer pretty quickly... The trick was to make use of doFirst. Working solution: 
    ext.greeting = "not set"

```
task configHello{
    doLast{
        project.greeting = "I said hello"
    }
}

task configGoodbye{
    project.greeting = "Goodbye"
}

task print(dependsOn: configHello){
    def localString
    doFirst{
        localString = project.greeting
    }
    doLast{
        println project.greeting
        println localString
    }
}
```

Gives:
:configHello
:print
I said hello
I said hello

Comment: I don't quite understand where you are going with this. Configuring stuff in the execution phase is, in general, a smell, as is configuring the same property from multiple tasks. Both `doFirst` and `doLast` get evaluated in the execution phase.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @PeterNiederwieser, and I know. The code, smell I mean. The real case was something along the lines of a 1. JavaExec task that does liquibase-stuff. 2. Several tasks are dependent of the JavaExec task, running before them. 3. Those tasks need to tell the JavaExec task to exec differently(different schema) based on context. 4. I would like to run the JavaExec standalone also, giving it a context.

Comment: Maybe you have some hints or link to best practice on configuration properties @PeterNiederwieser? Maybe a custom task extending JavaExec would be a better solution?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "best practice on configuration properties". In general, you should try to avoid conditional configuration. For example, you could have one JavaExec task per context, rather than one task that gets configured differently depending on the context.

Comment: "you should try to avoid conditional configuration" is a good tip that I was looking for @PeterNiederwieser . I can also see that this can quickly get out of control and my cravings for DRY has to make some adjustments for maintainability. Perhaps also readability.